# Wordpress Types plugin: export local conf to server

Tags: php, wordpress

When I have to make Custom Post Types or Custom Fields in Wordpress, I use **Types plugin** (http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) : it's a simple and fast way to register CPT / CF.

My problem is that the plugin stores all my registered CPT /CF in the db, so, when I have to put my local sites online / update online version, I have to drop my WP tables, and reimport from local export. It takes time, and it's pretty dangerous (if I make a mistake, I can drop wrong tables).

Is there a way to export/import/update Types settings easily from local to server ? Is it possible to make Types generates a PHP file that contains all registered CPT / CF (so a simple `git push` would update my server) ?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer my own question : I'm simply dumb.

**Types plugin provides an Import / Export function**...